# Python - find next function on setup

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, selenium

I am using Selenium tests. 
I have a class with many functions and a setup function that runs before every function on the class:

```
Class myClass (object):
    def setup(self):
        #something here
```

I would like to detect on setup function which function in going to run after. How can I do that?
Thank you !

Comment: maybe using a decorator that would run before every function. In that decorator, put the code you want to call before your function

Answer (score 0):

Unit-tests executes test functions in lexicographic order by their names.

> Note The order in which the various tests will be run is determined by sorting the test method names with respect to the built-in ordering for strings.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code

Keep in mind that if you care about the order of execution of tests then you've done something wrong: tests should be independent of each other and should not rely on the order they are executed in.

Comment: I know that the tests executes by order, but I want to save in variable the name of the upcoming function or an ID. it it possible ?